# Toggle visibility of checkboxes on and off using AlpineJS

Tags: alpine.js

I have a checkbox form on a profile page and based on whether they have ticked it I want it to toggle the visibility of further questions on and off.

I'm using something like this:

```
<div x-data="{ show: false }">
    <input type = "checkbox" @click="show = !show" :aria-expanded="show ? 'true' : 'false'" :class="{ 'active': show }">
    Tick this box
    </input>
    <div x-show="show">Checkboxes go here</div>
</div>
```

But this loads the visibility as automatically false when the page is loaded. How can I set the default visibility to be based on a variable (the Boolean behind "Tick this box", let's call it tick_box).

Thank you

Comment: You have to set `true/false` dynamically in `x-data` for the `show` variable. Which template system do you use on the backend?

Comment: I'm not sure, the app is a mix of Tailwindcss, alpinejs and python.
Is there not just some way to just set like <div x-data="{ show: $tick_box }"> ?

Comment: That's exactly what you can do, but you need to use the correct syntax of your backend system. Please edit your answer and add some context, e.g. the Python part where you load the `tick_box` variable from the database and render the final HTML template.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Inputs are self-closing tags.